# How to set System variables on ubuntu and retrieve it in scala

Tags: java, scala, ubuntu, apache-spark

in Scala, I am using ConfigFactory to store DB connection info and I want to put two db connection info and separate them using system variables. one for test server and the other one for my real server

my.config

```
real {
  MySQL {
    path = "jdbc:mysql:MY_DB_PATH"
    user = "root"
    password = "root"
  }
}
development {
  MySQL {
    path = "jdbc:mysql:MY_DB_PATH"
    user = "root"
    password = "root"
  }
}
```

I am getting connection info like this below

```
val env = if (System.getenv("SCALA_ENV") == null) "development" else System.getenv("SCALA_ENV")
```

but I don't know how to set system variable `SCALA_ENV` on command line on Ubuntu
is there a way how to do it?  or am i misunderstanding the way how it works ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since, as you mentioned in a comment, you actually need to go through a `spark-submit`, I would suggest you to use Java properties instead. You can specify them as you would for any Java program by setting the `--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="my.env=real"` option for `spark-submit`. You can use the same approach within executors by setting `--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions`.

You can retrieve those keys with `System.getProperty("my.env")` (nullable) in Java/Scala or `sys.props.get("my.env")` (`Option[String]`) in Scala.

You can find more info on these keys [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/configuration.html#runtime-environment).

I'll leave my previous answer here since it answers the actual question.

---

Regarding how you retrieve it, I can suggest using `sys.env`, a `Map[String, String]` that allows you to interact with environment variables in a more concise and idiomatic way:

```
val env = sys.env.get("SCALA_ENV").getOrElse("development")
```

Regarding setting the environment variables from the CLI in Ubuntu (or any other Unix-like system for that matter), you can do this quite simply in a launch script for your application:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

SCALA_ENV=real

java -jar your.jar -cp all:the:jars:you:need org.example.YourMain
```

Otherwise you can set it explicitly before running the process on the command line itself:

```
export SCALA_ENV=real # will be set for the rest of the session
```

Or also right before your command (so that it will be set only for that):

```
$ SCALA_ENV=real java -jar your.jar -cp all:the:jars:you:need org.example.YourMain
```

Where `$` is your prompt, of course.

---

You may also be interested in setting the environment variables as part of your build in SBT:

```
envVars in Test := Map("SCALA_ENV" -> "development")
```

Comment: it seems to work with `export SCALA_ENV=real` and then `scala System.getenv("SCALA_ENV")` but In my case, I am packaging scala with jar file and run it with `spark-submit packageName.jar` and it's not working here. sorry I didn't mention it before

Comment: tried `$ SCALA_ENV=real spark-submit myPackage.jar` and still not workiing

Comment: Of course it doesn't, it's only for the local process. I'll add this, but please edit your question, it's misleading.

Comment: Are you running on YARN or Mesos? Do you need the environment variable for the driver or the executors?

Comment: No, I am running spark only locally no YARN or Mesos

Comment: Do you need the environment variable for the driver or the executors?

Comment: I only need it for driver